# Replacing webpack requires dynamically

Tags: webpack

#### How I write my modules:

```
A/
 - A.js
 - index.js
B/
 - B.js
 - index.js
```

where `index.js` is simply `module.exports = require('./A')`

With this approach, stacktraces are more helpful and my editor's fuzzy filename matching is much more simple.

So, when I `require('./A')` it resolves to `./A/index.js`, and I want to replace all my `./A/index.js` to `./A/A.js` for a particular pattern.

#### What I tried:

I used webpack's **NormalModuleReplacementPlugin** to do this.

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
  /components\/(.*)\/index.js$/,
  o => {
    o.request = o.request.replace(
      /index.js$/,
      path.basename(path.dirname(o.userRequest)) + '.js'
    );
  }
);
```

But the problem here is that `index.js` MUST exist for this replacement to happen.

Is there any other plugin OR any other method that I can use to either

- ignore this and continue bundling for this pattern
- (OR) conditionally check if `index.js` exists then use `index.js` else use `DirectoryName.js`